# Imagick trimImage incomplete results

Tags: imagick

My results can be seen at http://cwstarkey.com/Capture.PNG

Trim is only removing the top, I would like all the whitespace removed, leaving only the (original scanned) text image. Any ideas?

My code:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->pingImage($imfilename);
$im->readImage($imfilename);
$im->trimImage(0);
$im->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0);
$im->writeImage(APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'receipts/'.$date = date('YmdHis').'.jpg');
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: Can you link an example source image?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear @Danack, see instead the image at http://cwstarkey.com/image.php Thanks for giving this a look!

Comment: @Danack, I found advise you gave some time ago to use one of the trim methods below, neither has had an effect:

    $im->trimImage(0.3 * \Imagick::getQuantum());

Or

    $range = $image->getQuantumRange();
    $image->trimImage(0.3 * $range['quantumRangeLong']);

From phpinfo(): 
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.9.1-2 Q16 x86 2015-04-14 
Imagick using ImageMagick library version ImageMagick 6.9.1-10 Q16 x86 2015-07-25

Comment: You have speckles on the image which is causing the problem, not sure what a reliable solution is yet.

Comment: Yep, didn't see them until another image worked fine. Thanks @Danack!